# innerHTML has value but only shows first element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate elements with JS after a Query to a SP List. The problem is I can't make a div innerHTML show changes in a loop. The HTML code is this:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="FXmasonryWrapper" id="letterContainers">
    <div class="bioBarTitle" id="letterButtons"></div>
    <br>   
  </div>
</div>
```

The function that generates the items for `letterContainers` and `letterButtons` is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var letters = new Array;
    var foundLetters = '';
    //QueryList( Repository, ListName, StartingRow, EndRow, SuccessCallback, FailCallback );
    QueryList( '/sites/SKCopspcs/testing/', 'QAVGlossary', 1, 1000, function( sender, args ){
      //Success -> queryItems
      var foundItems = queryItems.getEnumerator();
      var letterButtons = document.getElementById( 'letterButtons' );
      var letterContainers = document.getElementById( 'letterContainers' );
      var _all = "";
      var done = 0;
      while( foundItems.moveNext() )
      {
        var found = foundItems.get_current();
        var title = found.get_item( 'Title' ) + '';
        var definition = found.get_item( 'n5ud' ) + '';
        var letter = found.get_item( 'Category' ) ;

        if( !foundLetters.includes( letter ) )
        {
          foundLetters += letter + ', ';
          letters.push( letter );
          letterButtons.innerHTML += "<span class=\"bioTitle\" id=\"" + letter + "Span\" onclick=\"Show( this )\">" + letter + "</span>";
          letterContainers.innerHTML += "<div class=\"FXmasonry bio\" id=\"" + letter + "\"></div>";
        }

        document.getElementById( letter ).innerHTML += "" +
          "<div class=\"FXmasonryItem\">" +
              "<span class=\"titleB\">" + title + "</span>"  + "<br>" + definition +
          "</div>";

        _all += "" +
            "<div class=\"FXmasonryItem\">" +
                "<span class=\"titleB\">" + title + "</span>"  + "<br>" + definition +
            "</div>";
      }

      letterButtons.innerHTML += "<span class=\"bioTitle\" id=\"AllSpan\" onclick=\"Show( this )\">All</span>";
      letterContainers.innerHTML += "<div class=\"FXmasonry bio\" id=\"All\"></div>";
      document.getElementById( 'All' ).innerHTML = _all;
      console.log( letterButtons.innerHTML );

    }, function( s, a ){
      //Fail\"
      alert( 'Could not query list "QAVGlossary"' );
    });
</script>
```

`letterContainers` generates all of it's items correctly, but `letterButtons` only shows the first element (A button with letter 'A') and when I log the `innerHTML` of `letterButtons`, it contains all the span buttons! But only shows 'A' and in the DOM Explorer it only contains the first element (The 'A' button)! If I copy an paste the generated `innerHTML` (Which I log in console after everything is "generated") from `letterButtons` in the DOM Explorer, it shows everything!

Why does this happen?
`letterButtons.innerHTML` contains all the generated items correctly, but it's only showing one and I can't figure out why. I even surrounded the code with try catch, made logs inside the loop and there are 0 erros. Everything is correctly, except that `letterButtons.innerHTML` contains the correct value but show only the first element.

P.D: I also tried concatenating the items to a variable string ( `_genItems += "<span....>";` ) in the loop and in the end do the same:

```
letterButtons.innerHTML = _genItems;
```

And the result is the same but in this case it shows nothing. If I log the letterButtons.innerHTML value it contains all the elements but in the DOM Explorer it shows nothing.

Comment: How looks like the letterButtons HTML element?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: How does `queryList` get populated?  It's inside a callback, which accepts `sender` and `args` - that's suspiciously C#-like, are you sure the callback doesn't receive `queryList` as a parameter?  Can you provide the params of the callback as a sample data set so we can look at it?

Comment: letterButtons is a 100% width blue div that allows multiple small button tabs left floated: |A| |B| |C| |D| ...

The buttons should be generated according to the existing letter in the queried list (QAVGlossary).

I will try to make a fiddle.

queryList is a function I wrote and I use in all the SP Site. I makes queries to SP Lists with the SPClientContext. It really doesn't has any impact on how it is populated. I wrote the library and has been used on all the site for months.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to solve this issue I tried this with this piece of code:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="FXmasonryWrapper" id="letterContainers">
    <div class="bioBarTitle" id="letterButtons"></div>
    <br>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I took out the BarTitle from the Wrapper and now works. I really don't have a reason of why this is happening.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="bioBarTitle" id="letterButtons"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="FXmasonryWrapper" id="letterContainers"></div>
</div>
```